# Micronaut: Injecting a list of values with @Property to a test class does not work as expected

Tags: micronaut

How can I define some specific property for testing that is a list and not just a string?

The [documentation explains, how to do with string](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/index.html#junit5), but I can't set the `value` to a list of strings.

*application.yml*

```
items:
  - "Item 1"
  - "Item 2"
```

Test file:

```kotlin
@MicronautTest(environments = ["test"])
class MyTest {

    @Test
    @Property(name = "items", value = "Item 1,Item 2") // this does not work
    fun justWithOneItem() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

On the actual code, this works ([as documented here](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/config.html#_list_array_conversion))

Project file:

```kotlin
@Singleton
class SomeClass {
    @set:Inject
    @setparam:Property(name = "items")
    var items: List<String>? = null

    // ...
}
```

I know that I can create an `application-test.yml` and do

```kotlin
@MicronautTest(environments = ["test"])
class MyTest {
    // ...
}
```

But I would rather prefer to set it programmatically instead of creating a new env/yaml file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `@Property` to a test method like that would work if you would inject an `items` list in your test class. Something like this: *(I know it's Spock test, and not Kotlin, but you should get the point.)*

```groovy
package com.github.wololock.micronaut.products

import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Property
import io.micronaut.test.annotation.MicronautTest
import spock.lang.Specification

@MicronautTest(environments = ["test"])
class MyTest extends Specification {

    @Property(name = "items")
    List<String> items

    def "should use default items"() {
        expect:
        items == ["Item 1", "Item 2"]
    }

    @Property(name = "items", value = "Item 3,Item 4,Item 5")
    def "should override default items"() {
        expect:
        items == ["Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5"]
    }
}
```

However, you are using a bean of `SomeClass` that uses injected items. The thing here is that when you inject `someClass` object to your test class, the bean is already created and it is immutable. That is why adding `@Property` under one of the test methods won't reconstruct the bean object.

```groovy
package com.github.wololock.micronaut.products

import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Property
import io.micronaut.test.annotation.MicronautTest
import spock.lang.Specification

import javax.inject.Inject

@MicronautTest(environments = ["test"])
class MyTest extends Specification {

    @Inject
    SomeClass someClass

    def "should use default items"() {
        expect:
        someClass.items == ["Item 1", "Item 2"]
    }

    @Property(name = "items", value = "Item 3,Item 4,Item 5")
    def "should override default items"() {
        expect:
        someClass.items == ["Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5"]
    }
}
```

#### Output:

[image]

Luckily, there is a solution to that problem. You can use a `@MockBean` to deliver an implementation of `SomeClass` object. In this case, you can define a method that expects `@Property(name="items") List<String> items` parameter, thus adding a `@Property` annotation over a test method will override values passed to the method annotated with `@MockBean`:

```groovy
package com.github.wololock.micronaut.products

import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Property
import io.micronaut.test.annotation.MicronautTest
import io.micronaut.test.annotation.MockBean
import spock.lang.Specification

import javax.inject.Inject

@MicronautTest(environments = ["test"])
class MyTest extends Specification {

    @Inject
    SomeClass someClass

    def "should use default items"() {
        expect:
        someClass.items == ["Item 1", "Item 2"]
    }

    @Property(name = "items", value = "Item 3,Item 4,Item 5")
    def "should override default items"() {
        expect:
        someClass.items == ["Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5"]
    }

    @MockBean(SomeClass)
    SomeClass someClassMock(@Property(name = "items") List<String> items) {
        return new SomeClass(items)
    }
}
```

#### Output:

[image]

I have used Java and Spock Framework tests (Groovy) in my examples, but you should be able to achieve the same with Kotlin. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer, now I got the problem. I tried this approach with `@MockBean` but I get this error: `error: Cannot apply AOP advice to final class. Class must be made non-final to support proxying`.

My `SomeClass` expects a bean to be injected in the constructor that I am mocking with another `@MockBean` in the same test, besides the `items` list.

Comment: Opssss, sorry, I didn't know all kotlin classes are final by default... Forget about. Changing it to `open class` your approach worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have 2 options:

1. Use `@Property(name = "items[0]", value = "Item1")` and `@Property(name = "items[1]", value = "Item2")`
2. Change your test to implement `TestPropertyProvider` and provide the config via the returned map

Comment: the first option did not work, I think because of what @Szymon Stepniak said: "However, you are using a bean of SomeClass that uses injected items. The thing here is that when you inject someClass object to your test class, the bean is already created and it is immutable. That is why adding `@Property` under one of the test methods won't reconstruct the bean object."

Comment: The first option will set the items correctly in the context. You can make your bean refreshable if you want it to handle refresh events to get the new config. That is what @MockBean does under the hood